# Generating binned average radial profile of an array in physical unit in python

Tags: python, numpy, binning

I am trying to create an average 1D radial profile from a given 256x256 matrix in python. I looked into the image created from this matrix which looks the following:

[image]

As it is a physical image the whole physical box size is 0.038 parsec which corresponds to 256 small grids on each side. I am interested to make a average radial profile of this matrix from the center to box end and I want the x axis corresponding to real physical unit, rather than grid unit. In other words, I am trying to generate a profile like the following:

[image]

From the help of some other answers, I got upto this point:

```
import numpy as np

def radial_profile(data, center):
    y, x = np.indices((data.shape))
    r = np.sqrt((x - center[0])**2 + (y - center[1])**2)
    r = r.astype(np.int)

    tbin = np.bincount(r.ravel(), data.ravel())
    nr = np.bincount(r.ravel())
    radialprofile = tbin / nr
    return radialprofile 



center, radi = (len(Y)/2, len(Y)/2), len(Y)/2 # Y is my 256x256 matrix corresponding to this image
rad = radial_profile(Y, center)

plt.plot(rad[radi:])
plt.show()
```

however, it does not do the job,your help is very appreciated.